# Mysql convert varchar binary representation field to binary to do hamming distance calculation with bit_count

Tags: mysql, string, binary, hamming-distance, bitcount

I've a db table with a varchar(64) field to store PHashing data, as **64 chars** (1's and 0's ascii characters). I need to calculate hamming distance with a test hasta, and it seems that the most efficient way to do is using mysql **bit_count** function. The problem is that I haven't found any way to convert/cast/whatever the hash field in order to be **interpreted** as a byte(8) instead of varchar(64). Like:

```
> select hash from data;
"0000000101100111111100011110000011100000111100011011111110011011"
> select convert_to_binary(hash) from data;
0b0000000101100111111100011110000011100000111100011011111110011011
```

I cannot alter the data and convert all previous data into a binary field. Is there any way to force mysql to **re-interpret** a field as a literal, or any other alternative solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code:

```
SELECT BIT_COUNT( CONV( hash, 2, 10 ) ^ 
0b0000000101100111111100011110000011100000111100011011111110011011 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to use it like this:

> SELECT BIT_COUNT(CAST(hash AS BINARY)) FROM data;

Use [CAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) to convert the field to `BINARY` and pass the result to `BIT_COUNT`. Casting the field hash to binary will turn it into a string with the binary data type, but `BIT_COUNT` is able to handle that.

Comment: Casting produces a 64byte data, so I cannot compare it against 64bit literal. I can cast also the literal from string to binary, but it produces wrong results. For example, **select bit_count(cast("011" as binary)^cast("111" as binary))** returns 3 and **select bit_count(cast("101" as binary)^cast("111" as binary))** returns 2. If you do this with binary data, the reply is ok, and always 1: **select bit_count(0b101^0b111)**, **select bit_count(0b011^0b111)**